# How do I get posts to appear at mydomain.com/blog?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, customization

I'd like to use WP to manage my whole site, not just the blog. I don't want the blog to appear on the home page, but instead at mydomain.com/blog.

What I've done so far under Settings/Reading is to change the "Front page displays" from the default of "Your latest posts" to the other option, "A static page". So that allows me to have a static page for my homepage, which is what I want.

Now how do I go about getting the blog portion of my site (posts) to live at mydomain.com/blog ?

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Eddie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page), specifically step 2.

What you need to do is create a new page, name it "Blog". Make sure the permalink is http://xxxx.com/blog. Then, in Settings > Reading, select that page as your posts page.